# How do I turn off bullet list formatting all of the lines to bullet lists in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-office-2013, bullets

I having the issue of bullet listing all of the lines when I just wanted to make 1 line be bullet listed.

Here is a GIF showing what happens when I want to make "3 units" bullet-listed.

[image]

How do I turn this off? I don't want press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> every time I do a bullet list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the article "Formatting applied to one paragraph affects the entire document” at:

http://www.word.mvps.org/FAQs/Formatting/WholeDocumentReformatted.htm

~ Doug Robbins

---

**Solution:**

1. Press **Alt+F11** to display the Visual Basic Editor. Press **Ctrl+G** to show the Immediate Window.
2. Type:

   ```
     ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).AutomaticallyUpdate = False
   ```
3. Press Enter, and save the document.

---

**Note:**

Styles other than *Normal* will let you change the "Automatically update" setting in the user interface.

Instead of using the Visual Basic Editor, you can make use of the Apply Styles pane (Ctrl+Shift+S), type in the style name, and then click Modify; in the Modify Style dialog box, clear "Automatically update" and click OK.

~ Stefan Blom

---

[Source.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/word-2013-how-do-i-disable-the-annoying-bullet/a8eaafb0-270e-41ba-9e57-a58069149121)